# AppFabric installation failed MSI error code:1603 | File Already Exists

Tags: windows-8, installation, appfabric

I've checked many solutions including the PSModulePath and the AS_Observers and AS_Administrators groups with no luck.  Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an indication as to which file it's not able to copy.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

These are the output lines from the log files where the error occurs.

> MSI (s) (0C:FC) [12:57:34:645]: Closing MSIHANDLE (86) of type 790536
>   for thread 8904 MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:34:646]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=SCW_Localize_i,,) CAQuietExec:   MSI (s) (0C:C8)
>   [12:57:34:646]: Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=SCW_Localize_i,ActionType=3090,Source=C:\Program
>   Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe,Target="powershell.exe"
>   "-command \"$content = Get-Content \\"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1
>   for Windows Server\AppFabricServer.xml\\"; $content = ForEach-Object
>   -InputObject $content { $_ -replace \\"INSTALLPATH\\", \\"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\\\" };
>   Set-Content -value $content -path \\"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1
>   for Windows Server\AppFabricServer.xml\\" \"" "C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log",) MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:35:539]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=SQMTask_Localize_i,,) MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:35:540]:
>   Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=SQMTask_Localize_i,ActionType=3090,Source=C:\Program
>   Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe,Target="powershell.exe"
>   "-command \"$content = Get-Content \\"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1
>   for Windows Server\Consolidator.xml\\"; $content = ForEach-Object
>   -InputObject $content { $_ -replace \\"INSTALLPATH\\", \\"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\\\" };
>   Set-Content -value $content -path \\"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1
>   for Windows Server\Consolidator.xml\\" \"" "C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log",) MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:332]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=SQMTask_i,,) MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:332]:
>   Executing op:
>   CustomActionSchedule(Action=SQMTask_i,ActionType=1042,Source=C:\Program
>   Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe,Target="/action"
>   "SQMTaskInstall" "C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log",) MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:411]: Note: 1: 1722 2:
>   SQMTask_i 3: C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe 4: "/action"
>   "SQMTaskInstall" "C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log"  CustomAction SQMTask_i returned actual error code 1
>   (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside
>   sandbox) MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:412]: Product: AppFabric 1.1 for
>   Windows Server -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows
>   Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish
>   as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action
>   SQMTask_i, location: C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe, command:
>   "/action" "SQMTaskInstall" "C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log"
>
> MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:414]: Creating MSIHANDLE (88) of type 790531
>   for thread 8904 Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows
>   Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish
>   as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action
>   SQMTask_i, location: C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.exe, command:
>   "/action" "SQMTaskInstall" "C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log"  MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:415]: Closing MSIHANDLE (88)
>   of type 790531 for thread 8904 MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:415]:
>   Creating MSIHANDLE (89) of type 790531 for thread 8904 06/01/2013
>   12:57:36.414 [8204]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at
>   RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 398
>
> MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:415]: Closing MSIHANDLE (89) of type 790531
>   for thread 8904 MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:415]: Creating MSIHANDLE
>   (90) of type 790531 for thread 8904 06/01/2013 12:57:36.415 [8204]:
>   Detailed info about
>   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\tmp\HESYNZQU\Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Core.dll
>
> MSI (s) (0C:C8) [12:57:36:415]: Closing MSIHANDLE (90) of type 790531
>   for thread 8904

And this is from the custom acctions log

> 6/1/2013 12:57:34 PM EXEPATH=powershell.exe PARAMS=-command "$content
>   = Get-Content \"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\AppFabricServer.xml\"; $content = ForEach-Object -InputObject
>   $content { $_ -replace \"INSTALLPATH\", \"C:\Program Files\AppFabric
>   1.1 for Windows Server\\" }; Set-Content -value $content -path \"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\AppFabricServer.xml\" " LOGFILE=C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log ExitCode=0 6/1/2013 12:57:35 PM EXEPATH=powershell.exe
>   PARAMS=-command "$content = Get-Content \"C:\Program Files\AppFabric
>   1.1 for Windows Server\Consolidator.xml\"; $content = ForEach-Object -InputObject $content { $_ -replace \"INSTALLPATH\", \"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\\" }; Set-Content -value
>   $content -path \"C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Consolidator.xml\" " LOGFILE=C:\Users\Andrew
>   Middleton\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-06-01
>   12-57-15).log ExitCode=0 Executing action :
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.InstallHelper.SQMTaskInstallAction
>   SQMTaskInstall areguments -  /create /tn
>   "\Microsoft\Windows\AppFabric\Customer Experience Improvement
>   Program\Consolidator" /xml "C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows
>   Server\Consolidator.xml" Error: ERROR: Cannot create a file when that
>   file already exists.

Comment: Judging from the actions log, it would seem to be `C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\Consolidator.xml` that exists but shouldn't.

Comment: The folder C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\ doesn't show until the installer starts.  That's why this is confusing.  There's no evidence of the file.

Comment: Is it possible to de-select the `Customer Experience Improvement Program` if you do a custom install?

Comment: It's already deselected.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.  I had to manually remove AppFabric 1.0 as I am on Windows 8 and the setup.exe wouldn't let me uninstall.  No folders are left over, from the previous installation, but the script throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to remove the folder "Microsoft\Windows\AppFabric" from the Task Scheduler. For some how it was created before I run the AppFabric setup.
I couldn't reproduce this behaviour, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was having that problem.  I would try to uninstall CU1 update from the "Installed Updates" but I would get "an unexpected internal error has occurred".  My solution was to *reinstall* appfabric (which was already uninstalled, but not this update) THEN uninstall this CU1 THEN uninstall appfabric again.